# Имитация таблицы CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox, css-grid

Есть разметка вида:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='column'>
        <div class='item'>1</div>
        <div class='item'>2</div>
        <div class='item'>3</div>
    </div>
    <div class='column'>
        <div class='item'>4</div>
        <div class='item'>5</div>
        <div class='item'>6</div>
    </div>
    <div class='column'>
        <div class='item'>7</div>
        <div class='item'>8</div>
        <div class='item'>9</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Такую последовательность блоков `.item` важно сохранить, потому что они должны выделяться друг за другом. Блоки `.column` необязательны.
Необходимо визуально представить это все в виде таблички:

```
1  4  7
2  5  8
3  6  9
```

Проблема в том, что ячейки в одном ряду должны быть одинаковой высоты, но их размеры заранее неизвестны. То есть 1 и 7 могут быть маленькими, а 4 высокой, но следующий ряд должен начинаться ровно под 4.
Как установить связь между этими элементами, чтобы они подстраивались друг под друга? 
Flex, grid — все что угодно подойдет, лишь бы в хроме работало, только тыкните, пожалуйста, куда именно нужно смотреть, всю голову сломала.
Спасибо!

АПД: количество блоков `.item` внутри каждой колонки может быть любым, заранее неизвестно, сколько их, но, разумеется, в каждой колонке одинаково

Comment: на гридах можно сделать, всю нужную информацию можно найти тут http://css-live.ru/css/bolshaya-statya-pro-gridy-css-grid-layout.html

Comment: @МузыкаСергей Видимо, мне нужны подсетки, которые еще не реализованы?

Comment: посмотрите в сторону display:flex и на возможности этого свойства

Comment: @Anser, смотрела, не смогла ничего придумать

Comment: Вместо grid подсеток можно использовать `display: contents;`. Но это пока только FF и Chrome с включенным экспериментальным флагом...

Comment: @FurryCat А кол-во строк фиксированное или нет? И ещё: непонятно как вы поймёте что элементы относятся к разным строкам, если не будет блоков `column`, а вы сказали, что они необязательны.

Answer (score 2):

В общем, насколько я понимаю, на данный момент мою задачу нельзя решить во всех аспектах, если неизвестно финальное количество строк.
Максимально минимальным решением я считаю динамическую установку свойства `grid-template-rows` для контейнера. При этом блоки `.column` не используются, все элементы `.item` расположены на одном уровне.
При этом сохраняется необходимая последовательность выделения, а благодаря сетке `grid` можно управлять всем контейнером как таблицей.